# Как при помощи using объявить тип-член внутри шаблонного класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, using

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class A
{
    public:
    using Uptr = std::unique_ptr<A>;
};

class B
{
    public:
    A::Uptr a;
};
```

Это классический подход снабдить тип дополнительным подтипом-членом для удобства работы.

Когда я пытаюсь реализовать это для шаблонных `A` и `B`, компилятор говорит мне, что я сильно неправ:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    using Uptr = std::unique_ptr<A<T>>;
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    public:
    A<T>::Uptr a;// Error
};
```

Скажите, почему так происходит, и что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо указать `typename`, потому что компилятор не знает, что `A<T>::Uptr` это тип, а не член класса.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    using Uptr = std::unique_ptr<A<T>>;
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    public:
    typename A<T>::Uptr a;
};

int main() {
    B<int> b;
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, я привел не совсем точный пример. Уже поправил.

Comment: @MGNeo изменил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо.